# Plotting two parallel charged plate configuration in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a parallel plate capacitor setup with plates at x = -1 and x = +1 lying in the yz plane. I have to then show the potential varying in between them and the vector plot of electric field.

How can I generate the solid plates in 3D?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Gnuplot is the best tool for this, nevertheless an approximation could be perhaps achieved with parametric plotting, where the `x`-coordinate is fixed and `y/z` are directly mapped to the `u/v` parameters:

```
set terminal pngcairo rounded font ",16"

set xr [-4:4]
set yr [-4:4]
set zr [-4:4]

set palette defined ( 0 "black", 1 "#666666" )
set pm3d at s
unset surface
unset colorbox

set isosamples 100

unset key

set parametric  
set ur [-2:2]
set vr [-2:2]

splot \
    -1,u,v w l lc rgb '#333333', \
    +1,u,v w l lc rgb '#333333'

#or set larger ur/vr and use, e.g.,
#    -1,(u>-2&&u<2?u:1/0),(v>-2&&v<2?v:1/0) w l lc rgb '#333333', \
#    +1,(u>-2&&u<2?u:1/0),(v>-2&&v<2?v:1/0) w l lc rgb '#333333'
```

This would give you:
[image]